# React-Native: Google maps only showing the logo, beige background and the makter

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

I am trying to get Google Maps to work in React-Native, but I'm only getting this far:

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bmy9.png)

My code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

class Additional extends Component {
render() {
  return (
<View style={styles.container}>

    <MapView style={styles.map}
        region={{
            latitude: 4.895168,
            longitude: 52.370216,
            latitudeDelta: 0.1,
            longitudeDelta: 0.1,
        }}
    >

    <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={{
            latitude: 4.895168,
            longitude: 52.370216
            }}
            title={"titel"}
            description={"descriptie"}
            />
    </MapView>
</View>
  );
      }
}



Additional.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Second Screen Title',
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
        flex: 1,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0
  },
});




export default Additional;
```

I have followed this tutorial for the api key and adding google maps:
[Tutorial](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md/%22Site%22)

This is my second page, the other one page is using a weather-api.
But according to the live-debugger nothing is conflicting.

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

Edit/additional information:
I have activated my API on the google-api webpage.

Edit/additional information:
[My androidmanifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U59la.png)

Comment: My first guess would be that you don't use the good API key, you have to use the android (for android only) or ios (for ios only) api map key. (had the same problem this morning)

Comment: Oh, really? Can't use the general key? Guess I'll try to fix the mess I've made and look into that.

Comment: Sadly it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a bunch of permissions:

```
<permission      android:name="com.shop.shoppinglist.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
 android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.shop.addtask.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission 
 android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```